# preg_match_all with windows / macOS9 line endings

Tags: php, preg-match, line-breaks

I have the following code to create a little doxygen like

```
public function parserAction () {

    $code = file_get_contents('/www/htdocs/rumpho/application/controllers/parserStr.php');

    preg_match_all ( '/(private|public)?\s*function\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*?)\)\s*{(?:\n|\t|$)*(?:\/\*\*((?:\n|.|\t)*?)\*\/)?/msi', $code, $matches );

    var_dump( $matches );

    die;

}
```

it works when line endings of parserStr.php are encoded with unix but it doesn't work if the line endings are encoded with Windows or MacOS9.

Ideas ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special character you want is `\R` that matches `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`. You regex then becomes:

```
preg_match_all ( '/(private|public)?\s*function\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*?)\)\s*{(?:\R|\t|$)*(?:\/\*\*((?:\R|.|\t)*?)\*\/)?/msi', $code, $matches );
//                                                                 here __^^              and __^^
```